# How to run java class with main method in play framework 2.4

Tags: playframework

I am planning to upgrade from Play 2.1 to 2.4.

I have created an ad-hoc application to run a standalone Java class with the following main method:

```java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    play.api.DefaultApplication application =
      new play.api.DefaultApplication(new File(rootPath), 
        Test.class.getClassLoader(), null, play.api.Mode.Prod());
    play.api.Play.start(application);
  }
}
```

...and I will run this class from the console as `play "run-main Test"`.

In play framework 2.4 I was not able to find `play.api.DefaultApplication`. How can I achieve the above with the  new Play version? Also, is there any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Things have changed slightly in 2.4

You should use Server class

```
import play.Mode;
import play.routing.RoutingDsl;
import play.server.Server;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server server = Server.forRouter(new RoutingDsl()
                        .GET("/hello/:to").routeTo(to ->
                                ok("Hello " + to)
                        )
                        .build(),
                Mode.TEST, 19000
        );
    }
}
```